# How to delete several elements from list at once in c++?

Tags: list, stl

What program does is as follows:

The list contains product information which includes product id, name, price etc.

1. User enters product id
2. Check the id if it already exist in a list
3. So if the id matches the id in the list, it shud delete all the elements of that id (product id,name,price etc)

Any hints on how to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use a struct or class to store the product information, so it will be in a single element of the list:

```
struct Product {
    unsigned int id;
    std::string name;
    float price; // you could also use int and represent the cents
};

typedef std::list<Product> ProductList;


void removeProduct(ProductList & productList, unsigned int id) {
    ProductList::iterator it = productList.begin();
    while (it != productList.end()) {
        if (it->id == id) {
            it = productList.erase(it);
        }
        else ++it;
    }
}
```

Comment: is it necessary for me to put the break there?

Comment: @aayat: Changed the method, so it can correctly handle multiple elements with the same id.

Answer (score 1):

you can use multiset/multimap
they have [erase operation](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/multimap/erase/) that erases all occurrences of a key

Comment: are there no ways to do it with list?

Comment: you can go through list and look for that id

Answer (score 0):

Use the [erase-remove idiom](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erase-remove_idiom).  Assuming you're using C++11 lambdas make this easy.

```
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
class Product
{
public:
    unsigned int id;

};

void deleteProduct( std::vector<Product>& products, unsigned int productId )
{
    products.erase( std::remove_if( products.begin(), products.end(), 
        [&productId] ( const Product& product ) 
    {
       return product.id == productId;
    }), products.end() );
}
```

The `remove_if` algorithm moves the elements that match to the end of the list.  It then returns an iterator to the first element that can be erased.  The `erase` then actually erases the data from the list.